# Is it possible to use Quarter in DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

I use

```
DateTimePicker.ShowUpDown = true;
```

Is it possible to use Quarter Names in DateTimePicker Control?
For example: 
1 Quarter 2018 y. => (after click up button) => 2 Quarter 2018 y. => 3 Quarter 2018 y. => 4 Quarter 2018 y. => 1 Quarter 2019 y. and etc.

May be better to use some other control? like DomainUpDown? but how to automatize this in DomainUpDown control?

Comment: Did you write some code to try? Can you share it?

Comment: You can define a custom format (including your own text) with DateTimePicker.CustomFormat and DateTimePicker.Format = Custom. However since you want to display a number (quarter) that is not part of the DateTime itself, you will have to at least derive from DateTimePicker. The question is whether this will be easier than writing a UserControl from scratch.

Comment: Mr. Oliver, can you help me? just a simple how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone will need to use quarters in `DateTimePicker`: I decide to do it with `domainUpDown`.

```
private void Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string[] q = Enumerable.Range(0, 200).Select(x => $"{(x % 4) + 1} quarter {2012 + x / 4} y.").ToArray();
     Array.Reverse(q);
     domainUpDown1.Items.Clear();
     domainUpDown1.Items.AddRange(q);
     string currentDateTime = GetQuarter(DateTime.Now) + " quarter " + Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).ToString("yyyy") + " y.";
     domainUpDown1.SelectedItem = currentDateTime;
}


public int GetQuarter(DateTime date)
{
    if (date.Month >= 1 && date.Month <= 3)
       return 1;
    else if (date.Month >= 4 && date.Month <= 6)
       return 2;
    else if (date.Month >= 7 && date.Month <= 9)
       return 3;
    else
       return 4;
}
```

I will glad if it will help someone!!!